# Python (Scipy): Finding the scale parameter (standard deviation) of a gaussian distribution

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, statistics

it is quite common to calculate the probability density of a value within a probability density function (PDF). Imagine we have a gaussian distribution with mean = 40, a standard deviation of 5 and now would like to get the probability density of value 32. We'd go like:

```
In [1]: import scipy.stats as stats
In [2]: print stats.norm.pdf(32, loc=40, scale=5)
Out [2]: 0.022
```

--> The probability density is 2.2%.

But now, let's consider the inverse problem. I have the mean value, I have the value at probabilty density of 0.05 and I would like to get the standard deviation (i.e. the scale parameter).

What I could implement is a numerical approach: create stats.norm.pdf several times with the scale-parameter increased stepwise and take that one with the result getting as closest as possible.

In my case, I specify the value 30 as the 5% mark. So I need to solve this "equation":

```
stats.norm.pdf(30, loc=40, scale=X) = 0.05
```

There is a scipy function called "ppf" which is the inverse of the PDF, so it will return the value for a specific probability density, but I haven't found a function to return the *scale parameter*.

Implementing an iteration would take too much time (both creating and calculating). My script is going to be huge, so I should save computation time. Could the lambda-function help in this case? I roughly know what it's doing, but I haven't used it so far. Any ideas on this?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a programming problem. As noted in the question, the inverse function can in principle be brute-forced but far better would be to get the analytic inverse. Thus I have voted to close this as more suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought that maybe there is a scipy function for it. That's why I was asking here first

Comment: ppf is the inverse of CDF, not PDF --- which one are you inverting? If it's cdf, then you get the answer straight from ppf and the loc-scale transform `(x-loc)/scale

Answer (score 2):

The [normal probability density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) function, `f` is given by

[image]

Given `f` and `x` we wish to solve for . Let's ask [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) if it can solve the equation:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.abc import x, y, sigma

expr = (1/(sy.sqrt(2*sy.pi)*sigma) * sy.exp(-x**2/(2*sigma**2))) - y
ans = sy.solve(expr, sigma)[0]
print(ans)
# sqrt(2)*exp(LambertW(-2*pi*x**2*y**2)/2)/(2*sqrt(pi)*y)
```

So it appears there is a closed-formed solution in terms of the [LambertW function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), `W`, which satisfies

```
z = W(z) * exp(W(z))
```

for all complex-valued `z`.

We could use sympy to also find the numerical result for given `x` and `y`, but
perhaps it would be faster to do the numerical work with
[`scipy.special.lambertw`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.lambertw.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as special

def sigma_func(x, y):
    results = set([np.real_if_close(
        np.sqrt(2)*np.exp(special.lambertw(-2*np.pi*x**2*y**2, k=k)/2)
        /(2*np.sqrt(np.pi)*y)).item() for k in (0, -1)])
    results = [s for s in results if np.isreal(s)]
    return results
```

In general, the LambertW function returns complex values, but we are only
interested in real-valued solutions for `sigma`. [Per the
docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.lambertw.html),
`special.lambertw` has two partially-real branches, when `k=0` and `k=1`. So the
code above checks if the returned value (for those two branches) is real, and
returns a list of any real solutions if they exist. If no real solution exists,
then an empty list is returned. That happens if the pdf value `y` is not
attained for any real value of sigma (for the given value of `x`).

---

You can use it like this:

```
x = 30.0
loc = 40.0
y = 0.02
s = sigma_func(loc-x, y)
print(s)
# [16.65817044316178, 6.830458938511113]

import scipy.stats as stats
for si in s:
    assert np.allclose(stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=si), y)
```

---

In the example you gave, with `y = 0.025`, there is no solution for sigma:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 30.0
loc = 40.0
y = 0.025
s = np.linspace(5, 20, 100)
plt.plot(s, stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=s))
plt.hlines(y, 4, 20, color='red')  # the horizontal line y = 0.025
plt.ylabel('pdf')
plt.xlabel('sigma')
plt.show()
```

[image]

and so `sigma_func(40-30, 0.025)` returns an empty list:

```
In [93]: sigma_func(40-30, 0.025)
Out [93]: []
```

---

The plot above is typical in the sense that when `y` is too large there are zero
solutions, at the maximum of the curve (let's call it `y_max`) there is one
solution

```
In [199]: y_max = np.nextafter(np.sqrt(1/(np.exp(1)*2*np.pi*(10)**2)), -np.inf)

In [200]: y_max
Out[200]: 0.024197072451914336

In [201]: sigma_func(40-30, y_max)
Out[201]: [9.9999999776424]
```

and for y smaller than the `y_max` there are two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The will be two solutions, because normal PDF is symmetric around the mean. 
As it stands, you have a single-variable equation to solve. <s>It won't have a closed-form solution</s>, so  you can use e.g. `scipy.optimize.fsolve` to solve it.

EDIT: see @unutbu's answer for the closed form solution in terms of Lambert W function.

Comment: Yes, the normal PDF is symmetric and I have both, the lower (5%) and upper (95%) boundary (which is 30 and 50), so that won't be a problem.
I did stumble across scipy.optimize.fsolve, but didn't quite figure how to use it. 
But all in all it seems that it comes down to a minimalization problem. Thought that there might be a pre-implemented function in scipy but it seems there isn't :-/